# Get distinct columns with order by date

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have these following two tables:

```
Job Title | PostDate | CompanyId
Assitant  | 12/15/10 | 10
Manager   | 12/1/10  | 11
Developer | 12/31/10 | 10
Assitant  | 12/1/10  | 13
PM        | 11/29/10 | 12

CompanyId | Name
10        | Google
11        | Yahoo
12        | Microsoft
13        | Oracle
```

Now i would like to get 3 different companies with the jobs sorted by post date. The result table would be following:

```
Job Title | PostDate | CompanyName
Developer | 12/31/10 | Google
Manager   | 12/1/10  | Yahoo
Assitant  | 12/1/10  | Oracle
```

How can I achieve that using a linq query? Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Is this in LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that would be something like:

```
var query = from company in db.Companies
            join job in db.Jobs on company.CompanyId equals job.CompanyId
            group job by company into jobsByCompany
            let lastJob = jobsByCompany.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate)
                                       .First()
            orderby lastJob.PostDate descending
            select new
            {
                JobTitle = lastJob.JobTitle,
                PostDate = lastJob.PostDate,
                CompanyName = jobsByCompany.Key.Name
            };
```

It's a little odd to do a join and then a group - we could do a GroupJoin instead, but then discard empty options:

```
var query = from company in db.Companies
            join job in db.Jobs on company.CompanyId equals job.CompanyId
                 into jobsByCompany // Make this a group join
            let lastJob = jobsByCompany.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate)
                                       .FirstOrDefault()
            where lastJob != null
            orderby lastJob.PostDate descending
            select new
            {
                JobTitle = lastJob.JobTitle,
                PostDate = lastJob.PostDate,
                CompanyName = company.Name
            };
```

EDIT: Note that doesn't just take the top three results. Use `query = query.Take(3);` to just get the first three results.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the quick reply. I am getting following result with the first linq statement:

Job: Developer, Date: 12/31/2010, Company: Google
Job: Manager, Date: 12/1/2010, Company: Yahoo
Job: PM, Date: 11/29/2010, Company: Microsoft
Job: Assistant, Date: 12/1/2010, Company: Oracle

As you can see the oracle job should be #3 on the list but its not. It seems like it's not sorting properly by postdate. As for the second query, I couldnt compile it because of this line: CompanyName = jobsByCompany.Key.Name. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Emon: Ah, I thought you were only interested in the it being the latest job *per company*. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Works as expected. This was really helpful!!